# How should one GpuMat in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

In OpenCV to create an image Mat I'd usually do something along the lines of: `cv::Mat myImage` however when I use this method `cv::gpu::GpuMat myImage` to create a GpuMat I get undefined reference errors. I have noticed that a lot of people simply declare `GpuMat myImage` however `using namespace cv::gpu` leads to the same errors.

In short, how do I create a `GpuMat` in OpenCV properly?

Note: I'm still learning C/C++, so it's likely I'm missing something obvious (or not accessing the method correctly).

Comment: writing `using namespace X; Y y;` makes no difference to the linker over `X::Y y;`. What are the linker errors you're seeing? Are they from the `cv::` namespace or from CUDA functions?

Comment: It sounds like you didn't link with the appropriate library for OpenCV's GPU module.

Comment: did you #include the gpu.h header?

Comment: @vasile - if it's got as far as linking it's *extremely* unlikely to be a missing `#include`

Comment: I've got `#include <opencv2/gpu/gpumat.hpp> #include <opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp>` in the header, and there errors are http://pastebin.com/LzFhHVVB - Thanks

Comment: To help clear things up, here is my code: http://pastebin.com/Y5kGDLTa where imageOne is a cv::Mat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurred as I had not included the opencv_gpu231 lib, thanks for the help!